# Suppress a progress bar in R

Tags: r, progress-bar

The HOF function in the eHOF package of R automatically generates a progress bar. There is no argument in the function to turn off the progress bar.

Is there any way to suppress the generation of the progress bar outside of the function? (I am applying the function many hundreds of times, and the progress bars currently serve no purpose other than to flood my screen.)

Comment: It seems to use `utils::txtProgressBar()` which writes to stdout so you can wrap your entire call with `capture.output()` to suppress it. `invisible()` is for masking `print()` output and wont' work in this situation. You should also consider e-mailing the pkg author and make this a toggle-able option. I'd've tried to PR it into the pkg but it doesn't seem to be on github (et al).

Comment: You may also temporary redirect all output, cf  `sink` function.

Comment: Thank you all. As @hrbrmstr pointed out `invisible()` does not work. The `capture.output()` technique does work, but returns a character matrix, which is incompatible with the subsequent `Para()` function of the package. While I could parse the matrix and reformat it into a HOF class object, that seems to be too much work relative to just putting up with the progbars. So I am giving up on this foolish dream. Thanks again.

Comment: @andy did you try `capture.output(var_name <- function_call(params))` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per @hrbrmstr's suggestions.

```
# Load the library
library("eHOF")

# Generate a fake dataset
FakeData<-sample(c(0,1),250,replace=TRUE)
TestMatrix<-matrix(FakeData,nrow=50,ncol=5)

# Apply the HOF function to each column of the matrix, and suppress progbar
# Use invisible to prevent capture.output from printing the progbar
invisible(capture.output(Models<-apply(TestMatrix,2,HOF,1:50)))

# Apply the Para function to extract the model parameters
DesiredOutcome<-sapply(Models,Para)
```