# How to suppress downloading progress in HTML file

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using imfr package to download some IMF data series

```
library(imfr)
t <- imf_data(database_id = "BOP", indicator = "BCA_BP6_USD", 
                             country = "all", start = "1990", freq = "Q")
```

I prespecified certain parameters in a separate chunk before to suppress downloading progress

[image: downloading progress]

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, error = FALSE, results = 'hide', fig.keep = 'all')
```

However, neither of these options did the job. Moreover `results = 'hide'` suppressed all the output including text and figures.

How can I solve this issue without having a separate chunk for data downloading?

Answer (score 1):

You can capture all those downloads message and progress bar in `capture.output` and wrap it with `invisible`. (Got this idea from [this question and answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41070115/10858321)).

And then make a wrapper function `imf_data` which works the same (mask the `imfr::imf_data` function) but does not print all those download messages and the progress bar.

````
---
title: "IMF Data"
output: html_document
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)

imf_data <- function(...) {
  invisible(capture.output(dt <- imfr::imf_data(...)))
  return(dt)
}
```


```{r}
library(imfr)

t <- imf_data(database_id = "BOP", indicator = "BCA_BP6_USD", 
                             country = "all", start = "1990", freq = "Q")
```


```{r, comment=""}
head(t)
```
````

---

[image: IMF data output without a progress bar]

---

Comment: Thanks, trick with wrapper function worked. It even works without `invisible()` function. Just curious if the same can be achieved by using some chunk or r options.